# Django 1.8.4 Problems on WSGI Target

Tags: python, django, apache2, celery, wsgi

Need help. I've tried everything, but the error continues. The error log returns the following:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=3510): Target WSGI script '/var/www/project/project/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=3510): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/project/project/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/project/project/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
application = get_wsgi_application()
File "/var/www/project/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
django.setup()
File "/var/www/project/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
File "/var/www/project/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/var/www/project/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
 self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/var/www/project/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
from .celery import app as celery_app
File "/var/www/project/project/celery.py", line 4, in <module>
import celery
File "/var/www/project/project/celery.py", line 10, in <module>
class Celery(celery.Celery):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Celery'
```

My apache configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin email@email.com
     ServerName domain.com
     ServerAlias domain.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/project
     ErrorLog /var/www/project/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/project/logs/access.log combined

Alias /sitestatic /var/www/project/static
<Directory /var/www/project/sitestatic>
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/project/project>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess project processes=2 threads=12 python-path=/var/www/project:/var/www/project/project:/var/www/project/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup project
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/project/project/wsgi.py
WSGIPassAuthorization On
</VirtualHost>
```

I think the error may be in mod_wsgi in Apache as well as the import of Celery. Also, there is another project on the same server that is running on another virtualenv.

Comment: Did you make any change in the wsgi.py file? is celery installed? Can you confirm?

Comment: Celery is installed. My wsgi.py file has not been modified:

`import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ureport.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()`

Comment: Are you able to run celery, when the server is down? `celery -A project worker -B -l info`

Comment: Thanks guys. The error was fixed. First, I ran the celery as daemon [link](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html), after, I changed `WSGIDaemonProcess project processes=2 threads=12 python-path=/var/www/project:/var/www/project/project:/var/www/project/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to `WSGIDaemonProcess project processes=2 threads=12 python-path=/var/www/project:/var/www/project/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages` in apache configuration